# Django comments not posting to database

Tags: django, comments

**I followed [this example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/comments/example/) for django comments** (word for word) and cross-referenced with the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/comments/) but none of the comments are submitting to the database. What am I missing? This is my first time creating a form and the documents provided are not helpful or clear.

**Question**

Does any one know of a great tutorial for forms or comments that can put me on the right track (a google search has turned up 5 different ways to do it and none of them seem to be vetted)?

Comment: There is no way for us to know what you are missing when we don't know what you have. You need to add additional details- the code you've written, what works, what doesn't, what have you tried, etc.

Comment: I did exactly what is in the tutorial... Which is linked to the question. There is no point in repeating my code. I am asking if there is something missing from the tutorial that I should know about.

Comment: Thank you for being unhelpful. You're answer is wrong because there clearly is something missing. You could at least point me towards a better tutorial if you're going to bother engaging with this question at all.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, please stop referring to that page as a tutorial - it's clearly marked as an example. Secondly, you don't appear to have read the [actual documentation page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/comments/), clearly linked from the first line of the page you give and also from the docs index, which explains exactly what to do to get it up and running.